# Trigger .py file when JS page is opened on nodejs server browser

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, browser

I have a nodejs server set up with several JS pages. On one of them, I want a local .py file to be opened and run one time in the background. I DON'T need to generate a response from it.

I have flask set up already, but I don't understand how to incorporate that with my current React Javascript page (the one I want my python file triggered from).

In different instances, I have tried using:

```
var path = require('C:/Users/myPath/python.exe');
var nwDir = path.dirname(process.execPath);
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
var child = spawn(nwDir + '/test.py');]
```

as well as:

```
const spawn = require("child_process").spawn;
const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["/test.py"]);
```

but I receive this error in both instances:
TypeError: spawn is not a function

located at:

```
const pythonProcess = spawn('python',["/test.py"]);
```

lastly I have also tried:

```
var express = require('express'); 
var app = express(); 
const {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');

    var options = {
      mode: 'text',
      pythonPath: 
      'C:/Users/myPath/python.exe',
      pythonOptions: [],
        // make sure you use an absolute path for scriptPath
      scriptPath: 
      C:/Users/myPath/test.py', args: []
     };

PythonShell.run('test.py', options, function (err, results) {
  if (err) throw err;
  // results is an array consisting of messages collected during 
execution
  console.log('results: %j', results);
});
```

but I receive this error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

located at my response.js file:

```
var res = Object.create(http.ServerResponse.prototype);
```

Is there something I should be including in my server.js file?
Is there a way I can incorporate flask with my current JS page?

For reference, here is a basic version of my current JS file:

myFile.js:

```
import React from "react";
import Header from "../Header";
import Footer from "../Footer";

class SummaryPage extends React.Component {
render() {
 
    return (

      <div>
       <Header />
    
        <div className="container-fluid ">
          <b><h1>Update and Read CSV File </h1></b>
        </div>
    
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload/image" 
method="post">
        <input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
    <div id="dvCSV">    
    </div>
    </form>      
            
      
<Footer/>
      </div>
    );
  }
 }

export default SummaryPage;
```

To reiterate, how can I have a local .py file be opened and run in the background when my JS page is opened? I would also be happy if it had to occur with the click of a button. No response from the .py file is needed.

Thank you for the time.